# How to get device pixel ratio on MacOS using native APIs?

Tags: macos

I need to get the device pixel ratio to pass it into one library. Are there any APIs for this? Like this one in Qt http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#devicePixelRatio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than querying the scaling factor, you should generally use the `-convert{Point,Rect,Size}{To,From}{Backing,Layer}:` methods of `NSView`.

If you must, you can use the `-backingScaleFactor` methods of `NSWindow` and `NSScreen`.

Note, however, that the "backing" pixels do not necessarily correspond to physical pixels on the display, for various reasons.

Comment: which -backingScaleFactor methods of is best out of NSWindow and NSScreen.

Comment: @SangramS. Well, whichever is more appropriate for your purpose. Usually, you would use the `NSWindow` method unless you had a specific reason to use the `NSScreen` one. Of course, better to use the methods I mention in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: In my case there are multiple monitor(display)  case. And NSScreen method gives wrong output\

Answer (score -1):

I don't know is this the thing you want...

```
let ratio = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / UIScreen.main.bounds.width
```

Comment: I want to get devicePixelRatio like in Qt library, which is physicalResolution / virtualResolution

Comment: https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

This may help you

Comment: The question explicitly mentions macOS.